# Porting from Windows to Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I'm trying to port existing Windows application to Linux.

When I run it using Mono on Windows it runs ok. When i run it on Linux machine I get null reference exception. I have tracked it down to exactly last line from this code:

```
DataTable dtResultRows = new DataTable();
this.Connect();
this.Connection.Open();

string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.rp_users WHERE UserLogin = @UserLogin";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, this.Connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserLogin", login);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter (cmd);
sda.Fill (dtResultRows);
```

Issuing `sda.Fill` command somehow disposes of this, `sda`, and even `dtResultsRows` - and now I'm stuck why does it happen?

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using RejestratorProdukcji.Entity;
namespace RejestratorProdukcji.Repository
{
    public class UserRepository : Repository
    {
        public User GetUser(string login)
        {
            DataTable dtResultRows = new DataTable();

            using (this.Connect())
            {
                if (this.IsConnection())
                {
                    this.Connection.Open();

                    string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.rp_users WHERE UserLogin = @UserLogin";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, this.Connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserLogin", login);
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter (cmd);
                    sda.Fill (dtResultRows);

                    this.Connection.Close();
                }

                if (dtResultRows.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    User user = new User(dtResultRows.Rows[0]["UserLogin"].ToString(), dtResultRows.Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString(),
                        dtResultRows.Rows[0]["UserDescription"].ToString(), (bool)dtResultRows.Rows[0]["UserActive"]);

                    return user;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("not exists.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example which is failing?

Comment: I'm guessing that the SQL server is some machine other than the Linux box?

Comment: @RonBeyer yes, SQL server is standalone box, different than linux or windows box.
edit: however im able to trace this connection on sql server and see it's being executed.

Comment: FYI - Mono isn't the only way to make .NET cross-platform anymore. You could instead use [.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/) or [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) (for non-executable libraries).

Comment: When both Mono and .NET Core are your options, please go to .NET Core, which is officially supported by Microsoft to work in the cross platform manner. Mono clearly does not offer the same level of maturity and support.

Comment: The cross-platform components of .net core come from mono originally, as I understand it. When you’re using core on *nix you’re using a fair amount of mono, which is maintained by the open source community which includes Microsoft (Xamarin). Mono has also been around a lot longer than core, so I’m not sure in what way Mono is less mature.